# Android not allowing manual apk install

Tags: android, installation, apk, cyanogenmod, android-4.3-jelly-bean

My device is no longer allowing me to install apk files manually. The install screen shows up like normal, only it will not allow me to click the install button. I am allowed to click the cancel button, so the screen is still responsive and not lagging or frozen, but there are no error messages or any kind of UI element telling me what the problem is.

I've previously installed apps this way and I can't think of any settings I've changed since, especially not the kind that would break this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Running Cyanogenmod 10.2/Android 4.3.1 (Jellybean), install from unknown sources is checked. Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Can you try this, Go to setting -> Security, enable Unknown sources check box.

Comment: If you already have a version of this apk installed, make sure your new apk is signed with the same key and has a higher version number than the current version on the device.  Alternatively, delete the existing apk before installing the new one.

Comment: @RanjithSubramaniam I already enabled that setting

Comment: @iagreen it's not an app that I currently have installed, and it's doing this for all apk files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out. I was searching around and found someone with the same problem [here](http://www.thriveforums.org/forum/non-u-s-toshiba-thrive-help/16409-install-apk-problem-install-button-not-working.html). Their problem was Talkback, but I started experimenting with closing my running apps and Twilight turned out to be the culprit. Not sure what Twilight had to do with this...but can now install from unknown sources again.

NB: It's enough just to pause Twilight, you don't need to uninstall/disable/clear cache or even force stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1). Goto the package installer app and clear data and then try to install the app.

2). Boot to recovery, wipe cache and dalvik cache, reboot and then try to install.

If you are able to install from playstore then this should fix your problem. I hope it helps.